# Python from matrix to 1-D array

Tags: python, arrays, python-2.7, numpy, matrix

I need to convert B to a 1-D array
I have a matrix which I am trying to turn to a 1-D array.
However I am getting an array with 1 cell which holds the 1-D array.
How do I fix it ?

Python CODE:

```
import numpy as np


def computecoreset():
    a = np.matrix('1 2 19 22; 3 4 28 11')
    B = a.ravel()
    cal = np.random.choice(B, 3)
    return cal

print(computecoreset())
```

However:

```
B = [[ 1  2 19 22  3  4 28 11]]
```

Which is not the same as

```
[ 1  2 19 22  3  4 28 11]
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`a.ravel()` being a method of [`NumPy matrix`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matrix.html) would still keep it as a matrix and NumPy matrices can't be `1D`. So, instead we can use [`NumPy's ravel()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel.html) method to convert into a flattened 1D NumPy array, like so -

```
np.ravel(a)
```

Sample run -

```
In [40]: a
Out[40]: 
matrix([[ 1,  2, 19, 22],
        [ 3,  4, 28, 11]])

In [41]: np.ravel(a)
Out[41]: array([ 1,  2, 19, 22,  3,  4, 28, 11])
```

Comment: @hpaulj Ah nice! OP should consider that too. Thanks for pointing us there!

Answer (score 0):

Use `np.array` to define your 2D arrays.

The extra convenience of specifying data as strings, as in your example, and having a few methods proper to 2D arrays attached to a `matrix` object are, at least in my opinion, outbalanced by the minor flexibility of the latter data structure, in particular most expressions that involve a `matrix` lead to a `matrix` result, even if this is not what you're looking for.

E.g., the double matrix product, i.e., a scalar, when it involves `matrix` objects is a 2D matrix and you will see the following recurring idiom

```
x = np.matrix('1;2;3')
K = np.matrix('1 2 3; 2 4 5; 3 5 6')

V = 0.5 * (x.T*K*x)[0,0]
```

when you want the strain energy of an elastic system represented as free-standing floating point value.

Note also that, using `array`s, you have no more to write

```
V = 0.5*np.dot(x.T, np.dot(K, x))
```

but you can use the new syntax

```
V = 0.5 * x.T@K@x
```

That said, if you still want a `matrix`, [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40279602/2749397) by [Divakar](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3293881/divakar) is exactly what you want and you're right in accepting it.